# Raspbmc install failed - wget

Tags: raspbmc

Trying to get Raspbmc installed.  I use the windows installer to flash the sd card. Good. Next, I start up the board. It goes through the network install. Takes about 10 minutes, then resets. Ok, still good I think.

After the reset the "R" logo appears on my screen, and after a few minutes I get a tiny text message that says `Update failed - wget` and it just hangs like that forever.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

you ought to fix your network setup or use [`raspbmc-final.img.gz` (240MB) image](http://download.raspbmc.com/downloads/bin/filesystem/prebuilt/raspbmc-final.img.gz) that contains everything you need without network access.